# How to (automatically) add custom icon to a treemap using ggplot2 and treemapify?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, icons, treemap

I'm trying to illustrate land cover data by the means of a treemap. I managed to create a simple treemap and to "grab" some icons. Unfortunately, I struggle to include these icons into the treemap which would help to illustrate the type of land cover.

This is an example code:

```
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(category = c("forest", "greenland", "crops"),
                 area = c(20, 10, 70)
)
df$label = paste0(df$area,"%")

# load icons
library(magick)
icon_crops2 <- image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Agriculture_-_The_Noun_Project.svg/512px-Agriculture_-_The_Noun_Project.svg.png")
icon_forest2 <- image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/BSicon_FOREST.svg/500px-BSicon_FOREST.svg.png")
icon_greenland2 <- image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Wikidata_Morse_code_logo_grassroots.svg/600px-Wikidata_Morse_code_logo_grassroots.svg.png")

# add icons to dataframe
df$icons = c(icon_crops2, icon_forest2, icon_greenland2)
print(df$icons)

# plot treemap without icons
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

ggplot(df, aes(area = area, 
                     fill = category, 
                     label = paste(category,label,sep="\n"),
                     subgroup = category)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(colour = "black", place = "center") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This results in the following image:
[image: treemap land cover without icons]

Yet, I would like to have something like this (created with GIMP):
[image: desired result (here created with GIMP)]

Although I could insert the icons manually, e.g. by using GIMP, I'm looking for an automatic way.

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `ggimage::geom_image`. To place the images we could use `treemapify::treemapify()` to create a dataset with the coordinates of the rectangles which could then be passed to `geom_image` to place the images in the right rectangles:

```r
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  category = c("forest", "greenland", "crops"),
  area = c(20, 10, 70)
)
df$label <- paste0(df$area, "%")

# plot treemap without icons
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)
library(ggimage)

dat_image <- treemapify(df,
  area = "area",
  layout = "squarified",
  start = "bottomleft"
) |>
  transform(x = .5 * (xmin + xmax), y = .5 * (ymin + ymax))

dat_image$icons <- c(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Agriculture_-_The_Noun_Project.svg/512px-Agriculture_-_The_Noun_Project.svg.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/BSicon_FOREST.svg/500px-BSicon_FOREST.svg.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Wikidata_Morse_code_logo_grassroots.svg/600px-Wikidata_Morse_code_logo_grassroots.svg.png"
)

ggplot(df, aes(
  area = area,
  fill = category,
  label = label,
  subgroup = category
)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(colour = "black", place = "center") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_image(data = dat_image, aes(x = x, y = y, image = icons), inherit.aes = FALSE, nudge_y = .1, size = .1) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to do the job!